# Upload and save the image path to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to upload an image to my server and save the image path to my database,

How can I rename the file to its auto-incrementing id? And save the path to DB

I mean if I have a file **image.jpg**. when I upload the image I want to rename it automatically to corresponding id.jpg (eg 1.jpg, 2.jpg 3.jpg etc ) and save that path to the database.

Here's the code I've now. But it's not working.

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$lang = $_POST['lang'];

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$target = "img/";   

$fileTarget = $target.$fileName;    

$tempFileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

$result = 
move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);



$add = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO files(title,description,imgname,imgurl,date,lang) VALUES('$title','$description','$fileName',$fileTarget',CURDATE()),'$lang'");

if($add){   
echo "File uploaded successfully";
}
else{
echo "Sorry upload failed.";

}

?>
```

Here's my form

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="upload" method="POST"        action="upload.php" onsubmit="return validateform()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title"><br>
<input type="text" name="description"><br>
<select name="lang">
<option value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
<option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
<option value="Telugu">Telugu</option></select><br>

<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529896/how-to-upload-image-and-save-path-to-database .                                                Try looking for existing answers instead adding new questions.

Comment: I don't see where you trying to rename uploaded file. And also you should do that after you inserted record to db and got that records id

Comment: I haven't renamed it yet! But it's not even saving the existing name and path of thr image to database! It is showing error

Comment: I suggest to add an auto-increment column to your table, then, before inserting, you get the maximum ID, increment it +1, rename your image with the new ID and INSERT .

Comment: okay .. what error?

Comment: The error is "Sorry the upload failed"

Comment: I already have an auto incrementing id in my table! But it's not even saving the existing name into the db! What will be the possible error?

Comment: "Sorry the upload failed" isn't very informative message.. plus it's not upload that failing, but query.

Comment: Replace your useless "Sorry upload failed" message with `mysqli_error($conn)` to check why query fails

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with your insert query check here what the mistake I found...

```
$add = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO files(title,description,imgname,imgurl,date,lang) VALUES('$title','$description','$fileName','$fileTarget',CURDATE(),'$lang')");
```

There ')' is wrongly added near to `CURDATE()` and also a `'` missed for `$fileTarget` and not well-ended insert query you create use above code for the same,

Comment: That didn't work! I had an error there! I fixed it . But still the same error

Comment: then you try to debug this why this upload action is failed this answer is written because you have a problem with your insert query. If there any problem related to uploading then you have to provide error details why this upload action is failed.

Comment: @A.D. it's not actually upload failing. This message displayed when query failing. He doesn't event check if file was moved successfully.

Comment: @ArtOsiI think there he has to provide full mysqli error using `mysqli_error($con)` first.

Comment: b'cause which syntax error he has in the query was resolved.

Comment: The file is uploading but the query fails and shows an error message

Comment: @VithulTNair try edit part of code I think I found 1 error also.

Comment: Whats that? I couldn't find anything except the one you pointed out

Comment: @VithulTNair so have you tried `mysqli_error($conn);` and checked what it shows?

Comment: #If any of answer post helpful for your Question post then select any of the posts as an answer which provide you the best solution to help another user.